# filter a list of tuples using filter() function and lambda expression

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, lambda, tuples

I am learning Python programming;i'm trying to filter a list of tuples using filter() function and lambda expression. but there is something wrong.
The code I have tried is as follows:

```
state_and_population = [
( 'Uttar Pradesh' ,  199812341 ),
( 'Maharashtra' , 112372972 ),
( 'Bihar' , 103804637 ),
( 'West Bengal' , 91347736 ),
( 'Madhya Pradesh' , 72597565 ),
( 'Tamil Nadu' , 72138958 ),
( 'Rajasthan' , 68621012 ),
( 'Karnataka' , 61130704 ),
( 'Gujarat' , 60383628 ),
( 'Andhra Pradesh' , 49386799 )
]

filtered_object = filter( lambda s_a_p: [ s_a_p[0] , s_a_p[1] < 0 ] ,state_and_population )

print( list( filtered_object ) )
```

The list should print an empty list according to my given condition but it is showing all the elements

```
[('Uttar Pradesh', 199812341), ('Maharashtra', 112372972), ('Bihar', 103804637), ('West Bengal', 91347736), ('Madhya Pradesh', 72597565), ('Tamil Nadu', 72138958), ('Rajasthan', 68621012), ('Karnataka', 61130704), ('Gujarat', 60383628), ('Andhra Pradesh', 49386799)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda `lambda s_a_p: [ s_a_p[0] , s_a_p[1] < 0 ]` returns a non-empty list which, in Python, is considered a True boolean that, in turn, causes `filter` to accept the corresponding item from the iterator.

Write the lambda as follows: `lambda e: e[1] < 0`